# QGIS Field Pyculator Reclass

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator

I'm new to the QGIS Pyculator and need to reclass a field ('AP') based on another field ('Mag'). What I have so far, from the ArcGIS field calculator:

```
def Reclass(Mag,AP):
    if Mag>= 2000:
        return "M"
    elif Mag>80 and Vector_Mag<2000:
        return "L"
    elif Mag<=80 :
        return "S"
    else:
        return "UNCLASS"
```

With the expression as:

```
Reclass(!Mag!,!AP!)
```

How does this translate into the QGIS Field Pyculator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **FieldPyculator**, you will need to:

- Insert your function as a *Global expression* and remove the `AP` parameter as you can choose from the GUI which field you want updated.
- Slightly change your *Field expression* by specifying fields using `<Mag>` instead of `!Mag!`.

---

This is the global expression I used (not sure what `Vector_Mag` was so changed these to `Mag`):

```
def Reclass(Mag):
    if Mag >= 2000:
        return "M"
    elif Mag > 80 and Mag < 2000:
        return "L"
    elif Mag <= 80:
        return "S"
    else:
        return "UNCLASS"
```

This is the field expression:

```
value = Reclass(<id>)
```

[image: FieldPyculator]